# How to convert Whole Chinese String to English letters?

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

Currently I am converting German umlauts by using below code:

```
String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(displayName, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
```

I need to do the same for Chinese Characters; I need to remove this because of comparison of Strings.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Chinese does not have a comparable alphabet, so normalizing (aka converting to equal representation in English letters) a Chinese text is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be using the "**Google Translate API**"

Using this is super easy,

> https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de

Here,

Key = text to be translated

Source = your source language

Target = your target language

Once you make a GET request it'll return a JSON string containing your result,

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "Hallo Welt"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here goes the reference link,

https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started

Comment: How fast is this process

Comment: Based on your network performance. But the response should come within milliseconds.

Comment: Can I use it as REST service for windows app

Comment: Yes definitely. You can use it everywhere! @Query21

Answer (score 0):

It it complicated to do the same as with German umlauts, because in German, there is only one character. In chinese, it is the whole language that has special characters.

But if you still want to try it, you can use a chinese to unicode converter and test the characters' unicode to replace it by a latin character.

Check this [Chinese to unicode converter](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-unicode.html) if you still have the lust to do this.

Good luck !